# Getting a database output to show up in an input field

Tags: php, input

I'm looking to be able to get my outputted data from my database to appear into an input box, so that I have the ability to update the data later on. I am trying to echo the output into the input field, but it just displays under my input field. How could I do this?

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$stmt = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_players");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    $player1 = $row['player1'];
    $player2 = $row['player2'];
    $player3 = $row['player3'];
    $player4 = $row['player4'];
    $player5 = $row['player5'];
    $player6 = $row['player6'];
?>
    <div class="draftResultsWrap">
        <div class="inline">
        <?php echo "<div>" . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . "</div>"; ?>
        </div>
        <input class="draftBorder"><?php echo $player1; ?></input>
```

Comment: `<input value="<?=$player1?>"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Echo php value inside html input value

```
<input class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player1; ?>'/>
```